# How to enable SSL/TLS on the SKS keyserver?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl-certificate, openpgp

I have local keyserver that I can access using `http://serveraddress:11371`.

I want to enable TLS on that keyserver, how should I proceed?

Comment: Could you [expand on your question](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) a bit to indicate what you have done, and where you are with your efforts? As it stands, it basically sounds like you could put nginx (or apache, or haproxy, or many others) in front of your keyserver and do TLS termination there.

Comment: Also see [the official tutorial - *TLS Configuration*](https://bitbucket.org/skskeyserver/sks-keyserver/wiki/TLS%20Configuration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a reverse proxy which adds TLS, for example nginx or Apache. Furthermore, you need certificate(s):

- if you want to participate in the [`hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net` keyserver pool](https://sks-keyservers.net/overview-of-pools.php) have to send a certificate request to the pool operator:

  > Keyserver operators wanting to be included in this pool will have to send an OpenPGP signed message containing a CSR to a UserID of `0x94CBAFDD30345109561835AA0B7F8B60E3EDFAE3`.

  At least some time ago, there was a statement that Kristian Fiskerstrand (the pool operator) expects stable operations of the keyserver for some time before issuing certificates.
- if you want to offer the key server under an arbitrary domain of yours, you have to get a certificate for that domain on your own.

HKPS is usually offered on port 443, and using SNI to distinguish between the domains (if offering services on both your own domain and the hkps pool) is fine.